# Using pcregrep -M to search for a multi-line string

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, pcregrep

I am trying to use `pcregrep -M` to search for a multiline string.

This is the line in my script:

```
lineNumber=$(pcregrep -Mn '$firstLine.*\n.*$secondLine.*' $myFile)
```

`myFile` contains multiple lines of the form:

```
firstLine\n  
secondLine(with other characters here that I don't need to match)
```

I get an empty string for `lineNumber` and that's all.

What am I doing wrong?

What should I expect for the return value? Shouldn't `-n` give me the line number? And if so, which line number, first or second?

Should I use `awk` or `sed` instead and if so how?

Answer (score 3):

First, a working regex is needed.  If I correctly understand what you asking for, this will work:

```
pcregrep -Mn '^firstLine.*\n^secondLine'  myFile
```

Note, that this prints more than just the line numbers.  As per the `pcregrep` man page, it also prints the the matching lines.

If you want to print just the starting line numbers, try:

```
sed -n '/^firstLine/=' myFile
```

the regex `/^firstLine/` selects the first line and the command `=` tells `sed` to print the line number.

To print just the ending line numbers:

```
sed -n '/^secondLine/=' myFile
```

To get both and any line in between:

```
sed -n '/^firstLine/,/^secondLine/=' myFile
```

`awk` can also be used.  The line selection is similar.  The command to print the line number differs.  For example:

```
awk '/^firstLine/ {print NR}' myFile
```

#### Capturing the line numbers into a variable

The line numbers can be captured into a variable with command substitution:

```
lineNumber=$(awk '/^firstLine/ {print NR}' myFile)
```

However, if there are more two or more line numbers, that may not be useful to you.  In that event, if you are using a shell that supports arrays, such as `bash`, you may prefer to capture the line numbers into an array as follows:

```
lineNumbers=($(awk '/^firstLine/ {print NR}' myFile))
```

If you are unfamiliar with arrays, note that statements such as `echo $lineNumbers` will not display the entire array, only its first element.  To see the whole array, run:

```
declare -p lineNumbers
```